# Confusing Rocket League selection

Tags: menu, games

I play a lot of Rocket League and this menu selection still trips me up every once in a while.

[image: rl]

The correct action to get to "FIND MATCH", for a controller, is to press (A) on "PLAY ONLINE".

But I found myself when I first started, and sometimes still, trying to use the right D-pad button (move right) to get to "FIND MATCH".

I believe I do this because it's lined up exactly and I can see that next menu there. I treat it almost like a hover drop down menu. I assume other people have this problem.

**What could RL do to make it more obvious that you need to click (A) or is this a common theme found in games?**

*Other than putting "Press (A)" on the button itself.*

Comment: For the downvotes, let me know how to make this a better question. Not experienced on this site as I am on Overflow. Comments are more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely bad UX on their part and there a couple of ways of improving the usability.

To your point, yes, it is confusing the way the 2nd level menu is set up and shown. The idea is obviously to give the users an overview of what is present in the next level without having to go into it but the way it is shown is wrong. A couple of ways they could fix this is:

- By allowing the user to get into the next menu level by sliding the analog stick right (or whatever the button enables the **right-arrow movement**
- By mentioning the required button-press. Maybe by a visual representation on the menu-item or by having a simply-worded instruction text somewhere on the screen.